# Page doesn't reload after loading a video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

It's the following situation. I have a website, with an image and if you click on the image, the image should be replaced by a video which starts automatically.

My code for this looks like that:

HTML:

```
<div id="heaven-video">
  <img src="/images/heavenpicture_08.png" width="100%" height="auto" onclick="startVideo()"/>
  <video width="100%" height="auto" controls="true">
    <source src="videos/heavenmovie.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
      Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function startVideo() {
  $("#heaven-video video").get(0).load();
  $("#heaven-video video").on('loadeddata', function(e) {
    $("#heaven-video img").css("display", "none");
    $(this).css("display", "block");
    $(this).get(0).play();
  });
}
```

CSS:

```
#heaven-video {
  position: absolute;
  left: 38.2%;
  top: 16.9%;
  width: 29.1%;
  height: auto;
}

#heaven-video video {
  display: none;
}
```

This works so far (When you click on the image, the video will be loaded and when loading is finished the image will be replaced by the video and it starts automatically).

But if you want to reload the page now, it is loading endless. So nothing happens!

This seems, as if there is a never ending loop or something like this in the code. I think, maybe it is because of the EventListener? I tried to add this "$("#heaven-video video").off();" in the function which is called, when the event-listener is fired. But this doesn't change anything.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: `$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){    //YOUR CODE   });`

Comment: Are you sure your issue has anything to do with your posted code?? And as a side note, `$(this).get(0).play();` is just more boring way to write `this.play();` :)

Comment: Yes it must have! Because without my code everything works fine!

Answer (score 0):

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('body').bind('beforeunload',function(){
               //do something
               //$("#heaven-video video").currentTime = 0;
            });
            function startVideo() {
              $("#heaven-video video").get(0).load();
              $("#heaven-video video").on('loadeddata', function(e) {
                $("#heaven-video img").css("display", "none");
                $(this).css("display", "block");
                $(this).get(0).play();
              });
            }
        });
```